How to copy to a user's clipboard from an iOS home screen widget button tap using UIPasteboard.general.string?
I am trying to copy to a user's clipboard from an iOS home screen widget button tap using UIPasteboard.general.string.
It works perfectly in the simulator (copies text to user's clipboard), but does NOT work when running on a real device (clipboard is never updated with new text).
I can't find any mention in Apple's documentation saying that this is not possible (copying to clipboard from a home screen widget).
Does anyone know how to make this work, or know of any documentation Apple has saying it's not possible (then I'll just let my team know this)?
Below is my AppIntent code that is tied to a home screen widget button. Thanks!
import AppIntents
import UIKit
import WidgetKit

struct CopyToClipboardAppIntent: AppIntent {
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Copy to clipboard"
  static var description = IntentDescription("Copy text to clipboard.")

  @Parameter(title: "Text to Copy")
  var text: String

  init(text: String) {
    self.text = text;
  }

  init() {}

  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = text
    return .result()
  }
}

TL;DR;

Wrote code (an AppIntent) in Swift, trying to copy to a user's clipboard from an iOS home screen widget button tap using UIPasteboard.general.string. This is an iOS mobile app home screen widget I am developing.

Works perfectly in the simulator (copies text to user's clipboard)

[ISSUE] Does NOT work when running on a real device (clipboard is never updated with new text)



Are you running the app from Xcode on the real device? If so, do you get anything logged to the console when copying to the clipboard?

Also possibly related Q&As: UIPasteboard string returning null from Today extension and iOS - UIPasteboard not working outside app
